# Java OO design: interfaces and lists

Tags: java, list, interface

Let's say I have a class called ***MemberNio*** (containing a SocketChannel and other nio specific objects) which extends ***Member*** class.

The method *getMember(id)* and *getMembers* return *MemberNio* objects.
The layers of my application that don't need to know anything about the Nio stuff could just call the *getMember* method to get a member and use the supertype Member:

```
Member member = membersMgr.getMember(id);
```

But the problem occurs when I try to call *getMembers*:

```
List<Member> members =  membersMgr.getMembers(); // <- error, can't cast List<MemberNio> to List<Member>
```

That would force me to have ***MemberNio*** objects where I should only know about ***Member*** objects.

This is a recurring problem when I work with Lists and Interfaces/suptypes.

Comment: So why don't you return a list of `Member`s from your method?

Comment: Well some classes need to MemberNio objects, otherwise I would only use Members.
I could still create methods getMembersNio and another method getMembers, but it seems wrong to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use: -

```
List<? extends Member> members =  membersMgr.getMembers();
for (Member member: members) {
     if (member instanceof MemberNio) {
          MemberNio memNio = (MemberNio)member;
          /** Do your stuff **/
     }
}
```

To fetch the `members` using `enhanced-for loop`,  we used the concept of :- `Super type Reference pointing the Subclass object`.  So, no matter which `subclass` objects are stored in the `list`, we always use a `super-class` reference to point to them.. And then `TypeCast` accordingly by checking the actual `instance type`..

And make the return type of `getMembers()` the same.. It would work.

That way you can return `List` of `Member` or any class that `extends your Member` class.. And you don't need to give the name of those class explicitly..

Comment: But if I loop through the members objects of the list, how can I get a MemberNio object?
List<? extends Member> members =  membersMgr.getMembers();
for (MemberNio member : members) // <- error

Answer (score 1):

Generics are `invariant` in nature. it means that  `List<MemberNio>` is not subtype of `List<Member>`
You can use [wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) to specify bounds.

```
 List<? extends Member> which means List of Member or any subclass of Member
```